# Open XML document from Results Tab in Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, xml

When I run my query using FOR XML PATH, is gives produces a link under the Results Tab. I have to click that link, then it opens the XML file and it looks good.

Is there a way, within a query, to have this file automatically opened once the query executes?

When I open the XML results, it makes the XML in a temp folder and I have scripted VBS to rename this temp file then move it to a specified network location.

Is it possible to have the results opened from the query?

Thanks.

Comment: Simple answer is no.  You can write some code to save the data to a file on the servers HD or a UNC location the server can access.

Comment: This would be even better! Have any ideas?

Comment: I use BCP http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx to write data to the HD. I have not used it for XML but I am sure you can find some posts from others that have.

Comment: I have tried this utility, but it is unable to process my query. It seems I can only export data from one single table.